# Preferences not working

Tags: java, android

I have this small code snippet which accesses my preferences so that when my checkbox is 'true' then splash music plays. Otherwise it does not. The tutorial I am following works with this code, but mine does not. Can anyone see a problem with my code?

When I run the app, the music plays regardless but I don't get any errors.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.clip1);

    SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    boolean musicCheck = getPrefs.getBoolean("checkbox",true);
    if (musicCheck == true){
        ourSong.start();
    }
```

Preferences XML:

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:title="EditText"
    android:key="name"
    android:summary="Enter your name"/>

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:title="Music"
    android:defaultValue="True"
    android:key="Checkbox"
    android:summary="For the Splash Screen"/>

<ListPreference
    android:title="List"
    android:key="list"
    android:summary="This is a list"
    android:entries="@array/list"
    android:entryValues="@array/lvalues"
    ></ListPreference>
```

Comment: The default value here is true. So if you aren't editing the value properly, it'll always be true. Show us the code where you save the checkbox value to SharedPreferences.

Comment: Is the name of the preference actually "checkbox"?  If you don't have a preference by that name you default to true, so my guess is the preference doesn't exist, you misnamed it somewhere, and so you're getting the default.

Comment: Show your preferences xml, please

Comment: I have eddited it to show my XML

Comment: `"Checkbox" != "checkbox"`

Comment: Ah, thank you.  That is the thing that I as a new programmer finds really annoying is sometimes missing a capital letter, since it always looks the same to me.

Comment: Please do your users a favour.  If there is one thing worse than a splash screen, it's a splash screen that plays music.  It would be enough for me to uninstall an app unless I *really* needed it.

Answer (score 1):

Change `boolean musicCheck = getPrefs.getBoolean("checkbox",true);` to

`boolean musicCheck = getPrefs.getBoolean("Checkbox",true);`

I believe the name of the preference you are getting needs to match the preference's key.